# Changing ng-click to ng-mouseenter doesn't call expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am working with [this Ionic directive on GitHub.](https://github.com/aquint/ion-alpha-scroll)

I want it to work so that the user can drag on the scroll bar, so to begin with I am trying to get the letters to work on ng-mouseenter instead of ng-click. On line 20 here, I am making that change.

https://github.com/aquint/ion-alpha-scroll/blob/master/src/ion-alpha-scroll.js#L20

However, when I do that, the function `alphaScrollGoToList` is no longer called.

Unfortunately, I may not post the project I am working on. I am hoping that I am missing something simple here.

edit: What's weird is that the HTML seems to be generated fine, something like this:

```
<li class="ng-binding" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet | orderBy: letter" ng-mouseenter="alphaScrollGoToList('index_O')">O</li>
```

But when the function is called, it gets passed `index_{{letter}}`

Comment: Are you testing in a browser or on the iOS emulator?

Comment: @SteamDev Browser